# Queue to Handle Multiple Structure Types [C]

Tags: c, queue

I'm trying to reuse a generic queue module (push, pop, init etc.) to handle storing several different structures.

For example I have the following modules:

main.c
queue.c
task1.c
task2.c

Task 1 and task 2 both have their own unique structures (task_1_t, and task_2_t) they need to queue. I'm thinking of implementing the queue as a simply array of uint8. Then I could just pass the structures to the queue_push function cast as an array of uint8 along with sizeof(task_x_t) and copy the data into the queue. Then when I pop I can just return a pointer to the array and cast it back to the correct task_x_t.

Does this make sense? Is there a better way to solve this problem?

#### queue.h

```
#define MAX_QUEUE_LEN       300

/**
 * @brief Queue entry
 */
typedef struct queue_data
{
  uint8_t data[MAX_QUEUE_DATA];       /**< Data array */
} queue_data_t;

/**
 * @brief Structure to represent a queue
 */
typedef struct seque
{
  uint8_t       head;                 /**< Index of head */
  uint8_t       tail;                 /**< Index of tail */
  uint8_t       size;                 /**< Size of queue */
  uint8_t       capacity;             /**< Max size of queue */
  size_t        dataSize;             /**< Size of data structure to be stored in queue */
  queue_data_t  data[];               /**< Array of queue entries */
} seque_t;

/**
 * @brief Queue error messages
 */
typedef enum
{
    QUEUE_OK,                           /**< Command successful */
    QUEUE_ERROR,                        /**< General error */
    QUEUE_EMPTY,                        /**< Queue is empty */
    QUEUE_FULL                          /**< Queue is full */
} queue_error_t;

/* Function Prototypes */
seque_t *     queueInitialize   ( uint8_t capacity );
void          queueDeInitialize ( seque_t * q );
bool          queueIsFull       ( seque_t * queue );
bool          queueIsEmpty      ( seque_t * queue );
uint8_t       queueGetSize      ( seque_t * queue );
queue_error_t queuePush         ( seque_t * queue, void * data, uint16_t len );
queue_error_t queuePop          ( seque_t * queue, uint8_t ** item );
queue_error_t queueHead         ( seque_t * queue, uint8_t ** item );
void          queuePrint        ( seque_t * queue );
queue_error_t queueClear        ( seque_t * queue );
```

#### queue.c

```
/**@brief Initializes a queue of given capacity. Size of the queue is initialized as 0
 * @details Sets the read and write pointers to 0
 *
 * @param[in]  capacity - number of elements in the queue
 *
 * @return Pointer to the queue object
 */
seque_t * queueInitialize( uint8_t capacity )
{
    uint16_t size = sizeof(seque_t) + (sizeof(queue_data_t) * capacity);
    Log_Write(LOG_DEBUG, "Size = %d\r\n", size);

    seque_t * queue = (seque_t*) malloc(sizeof(seque_t) + (sizeof(queue_data_t) * capacity));

    if (queue == NULL)
    {
        return NULL;
    }

    queue->capacity = capacity;
    queue->size     = 0;
    queue->head     = 0;
    queue->tail     = capacity -1;
    return queue;
}

/**@brief DeInitializes a queue. Frees the memory allocated for that queue
 * @param[in]  q - pointer to the queue to free
 */
void queueDeInitialize( seque_t * q )
{
  free(q);
}


/**@brief Returns true if the queue is full. The queue is full when it's size
 *        is equal to it's capacity
 *
 * @param[in]  queue - pointer to the queue to check
 *
 * @return Whether or not the queue is full
 */
bool queueIsFull( seque_t * queue )
{
    return (queue->size == queue->capacity);
}


/**@brief Returns true if the queue is empty. The queue is full when it's size is 0
 *
 * @param[in]  queue - pointer to the queue to check
 *
 * @return Whether or not the queue is empty
 */
bool queueIsEmpty(seque_t* queue)
{
    return queue && (queue->size == 0);
}

/**@brief Returns the size of the queue
 *
 * @param[in]  queue - pointer to the queue to check
 *
 * @return Number of entries in the queue
 */
uint8_t queueGetSize(seque_t* queue)
{
    return queue->size;
}


/**@brief Adds an item to the queue. Changes the tail and size of queue
 *
 * @param[in]  queue - pointer to the queue to push to
 * @param[in]  item  - pointer to start of data to push to queue
 * @param[in]  len   - number of bytes to copy
 *
 * @return None
 */
queue_error_t queuePush(seque_t * queue, void * data, uint16_t len)
{
    if (queueIsFull(queue))
    {
        return QUEUE_FULL;
    }
    if (len > sizeof(queue_data_t))
    {
        len = sizeof(queue_data_t);
    }

    /* Increment tail counter */
    queue->tail = (queue->tail + 1) % queue->capacity;

    /* Copy Data */
    memcpy(queue->data[queue->tail].data, data, len);

    /* Update queue size */
    queue->size = queue->size + 1;

    return QUEUE_OK;
}


/**@brief Remove an item from the queue. Changes the head of queue
 *
 * @param[in]  queue - pointer to the queue to pop from
 *
 * @return The popped item
 */
queue_error_t queuePop(seque_t* queue, uint8_t ** item)
{
    if (queueIsEmpty(queue))
    {
        return QUEUE_EMPTY;
    }
    *item = queue->data[queue->head].data;
    queue->head = (queue->head + 1)%queue->capacity;
    queue->size = queue->size - 1;
    return QUEUE_OK;
}

/**@brief Function to get head of queue
 *
 * @param[in]  queue - pointer to the queue to get the head of
 * @param[out] item - double pointer to structure to hold the data
 *
 * @return Error code
 */
queue_error_t queueHead(seque_t* queue, uint8_t ** item)
{
    if (queueIsEmpty(queue))
    {
        return QUEUE_EMPTY;
    }
    *item = queue->data[queue->head].data;
    return QUEUE_OK;
}


/**@brief Function to clear a queue
 *
 * @param[in]  queue - pointer to the queue to clear
 *
 * @return Error code
 */
queue_error_t queueClear ( seque_t * queue )
{
  queue->size     = 0;
  queue->head     = 0;
  queue->tail     = queue->capacity -1;
  return QUEUE_OK;
}
```

#### Modified the queueHead / queuePop functions like so:

```
/**@brief Function to peek at the head of queue
 *
 * @param[in]  queue - pointer to the queue to get the head of
 * @param[out] item -  pointer to structure to hold the data
 *
 * @return Error code
 */
queue_error_t queuePeek(seque_t * queue, void * item)
{
  if (queueIsEmpty(queue))
  {
    return QUEUE_EMPTY;
  }

  /* Copy out the data */
  memcpy(item, queue->data[queue->head].data, queue->dataSize);

  return QUEUE_OK;
}
```

Comment: As the `pop` function needs to know how many bytes to pull, you either need to have a message length or a structure type identifier as first element.

Comment: If the pop function just returns a pointer to the data array then the caller of the pop should be able to handle that I think

Comment: @Even in this case, the caller would need to know what to expect at the other end of that pointer.

Comment: It's interesting that `queueIsEmpty(NULL)` will return false.

Comment: Your code does not maintain clear ownership boundaries. You are returning pointers to data in queue slots that are no longer in the queue head to queue tail zone. In other words, you are definitely not thread safe and could have some serious bugs in any case.

Comment: `queue->size = queue->size - 1;` should be `queue->size -= 1`;

Comment: Never cast the `malloc` return, `void` pointers implicitly convert to any other pointer types.

Comment: Noted about casting malloc and the decrementer. Could you please expand on the ownership boundaries you're referring to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `void *` for polymorphism in C. A `void *` can point to any type of object, so you write generic functions like `queue_push` and `queue_pop` that take pointers to the objects to be pushed and popped in the form of a `void *`. The `queue_push`/`queue_pop` code doesn't care what the type being pointed to is and the caller knows the type so it can be cast back to the correct type when needed.

Some things to consider when designing interfaces of this kind, particularly queues, which often have different threads pushing than popping, are object ownership and lifetime. If you initialize a local struct in some function and then push a pointer to that struct onto your queue, who owns that object? The object lifetime is either the time between entering and exiting the function, or the time until the struct is reinitialized for any reason. The pointer on the queue could be pointing to memory that has been overwritten by another function call. The solution is to avoid pushing pointers to temporary variables, but to do that, you either make them static, which are inherently dangerous in multi-threaded environments or allocate memory on the heap.

Whenever you get a pointer from the heap (`malloc`/`calloc`), you must eventually call `free` to return that memory to the heap. A common approach is that whoever allocates an object is responsible for its entire lifetime and must arrange to deallocate it at some point. This lets the queue interface designer off the hook, as they only have to write queue code and can leave it up to their clients to manage object lifetimes. They simply document the fact that ownership of the object pointed to falls to the queue code for the period of time the object is tracked in the queue, ie; between the `queue_push` and `queue_pop` calls. The queue user must arrange for the object lifetime to exceed that period of time.

As the queue user, it is a general best practice that the code that pushes the object pointer is responsible for allocating that memory and the code that pops it is responsible for deallocating it. This simplifies object lifetime management, as to do otherwise, requires some means of tracking ownership of every object. In other words, is the object being initialized, in the queue, otherwise being used/manipulated by random client code, etc. I can explain how to do that tracking if you really think you need it.

Addendums:

Ok, now that you've posted your MCVE, I have the following comments:

There are two primary data storage techniques when it comes to containers like queues. One is to only store pointers to the users data and the other is to copy data into and out of the container. You are not doing either one consistently. You `memcpy` in `queuePush`, but not in `queuePop` or `queueHead`. Never allow client code to access your internal data, it's just asking for trouble.

Your `queueHead` is apparently intended to be a peek function. It should either copy the data out without popping it from the queue, or it should lock the queue from being popped until the caller is done peeking at the data. Personally, I never allow client code to access my internals, it causes too many problems in the long haul. Ask yourself if you really need to have this functionality, otherwise, get rid of it. If you do keep it and you continue to use the copy on push/pop paradigm, then copy on peek as well. You can add a `queueDiscardHead` function for clients that want to always peek before popping and avoid the extra copy.

Comment: Would it be possible to use something like this while maintaining some level of type checking using unions?

Comment: Yes, it is a common enough practice to use a `struct` with a union of pointer types and an enum or integer code indicating which type is currently pointed to. This can be very useful in cases where conversion functions are desirable and simple type casts from one pointed to type to the another is not feasible.

Comment: BTW: Given `void *pvoid; int *pint;` you can write `pvoid = pint;` or `pint = pvoid` without having to statically cast them. But you can't write `int i = *pvoid;`.

Comment: The way I'm currently working around the issue about ownership that you present is by allocating memory of MAX_QUEUE_SIZE * QUEUE_CAPACITY for each queue on initialization. This leaves me with a lot of underutilized reserved memory but my part has 128kB of RAM so I'm not too concerned about this and with the device running for months on end I'm more concerned about memory leaks.

So when I do a queue push, I copy the buffer to the space allocated for the queue.

Comment: Copy on push/pop is viable, you just add a `size_t size` parameter to your queue initialization function and pass it `sizeof(msgtype)`. Push and Pop then copy through the void pointer whatever number of bytes the queue was initialized for.

Comment: How are you managing that block of memory?

Comment: I allocate that block on initialization of the module and free it on deinitialization (which doesn't usually happen during the life of the application)

Comment: Sure, but how do you manage the blocks of memory within that block? You must be implementing some form of memory management. Since you have not posted an [MCVE], we can only guess at the complexity of the code you have written to manage that memory.

Comment: Sorry- updated with queue module.